# Simple question. How do you solve and factorize this using a CAS tool?

Tags: polynomials, maple

Simple question for you awesome guys :)

I've got the formular for a polynomial:

```
7x^4-56x^3+224x^2-56x+231=0
```

The thing i need to do is to solve and factorize the above equation.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a real solution? (There are no real solutions.)

Comment: In this case, i guess it's a complex solution :)

Comment: Maxima didn't factor it for me...

Comment: My answer is also only based on the help page, I haven't tested whether it works with the given polynomial.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7x%5E4-56x%5E3%2B224x%5E2-56x%2B231%3D0&dataset=

Comment: Not that it matters, but you might as well use $x^4-8x^3+32x^2-8x+33 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Besides to another answer, you can use the `fsolve` command. Firstly define your polynomial as

> `p:=7x^4-56x^3+224x^2-56x+231;`

in Maple environment and then enter the following command as I pointed:

> `fsolve(p=0);`

As you see below, I check of probable solutions by making a plot. It tells us that `p=0` has no real solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `factor` command will help you. For example

```
factor(x^3+5,complex)
```

Will factor your polynomial in the complex plane. See the maple help [here.](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=factor)

Comment: I like your avatar.

Comment: I hope I don't get into any trouble if I admit that this was a logo from some Mozilla side regarding thunderbird. If so, I will of course change it, though I never thought about it. Just liked the guy on the picture.

Comment: It is soooo funny to me. $\ddot\smile$